# Android RxJava remember variable

Tags: android, arrays, json, string, rx-java

I'm learning RxJava.

#### My data:

- String variable - command

#### My goal:

- Split string (*space* as regular expression) - *done*
- Check if array has elements - *done*
- Map array into strings (foreach) - *done*
- Important thing: I have to remember my 1st string after split, because it is required in subscribe
- I know that my 2nd string is optional. If exists then it could be json or regular string
- I have to know what is in 2nd string (isn't exist/json/regular string) and execute different actions (subscribe).

#### My code:

```
Observable.just(command)
                .map(s -> s.split(" "))
                .filter(strings -> strings.length > 0)
                .flatMap(Observable::from)
//                .remember my first string
                .skip(1)
                .filter(s1 -> s1 != null)
//                .handle if s1 == null - it means that 2nd string does not exitst
                .map(this::getJson)
//                .onErrorResumeNext( * subscribe on that string element*) // regular string
//              IF getJson return JSONObject
//                .subscribe(jsonObject -> myMethod(firstString, jsonObject))
```

Am I thinking about it in right way? How to do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you `flatMap` your `String` array and skip your first `String`, you'll lost this first `String`.

If you want to work with this first and second String, you'll have to emit them both.

```
Observable.just(command)
              .map(s -> s.split(" "))
              .filter(strings -> strings.length > 0)
              .flatMap(arr -> {
                  // transform the second args as a Json Object
                  Observable<Object> jsonObject = Observable.from(arr)
                                                            .skip(1)
                                                            .map(this::getJson);

                  // get the first String
                  Observable<String> firstArg = Observable.from(arr)
                                                          .take(1);
                  // call myMethod with the first String and the jsonObject
                  return Observable.combineLatest(firstArg, jsonObject, (first, second) -> myMethod(first, second))
                                   // call fallback method if you haven't a second arg 
                                   .switchIfEmpty(firstArg.map(f -> fallbackMethod(m)));

              })
              .subscribe();
```